# telnet session sending 'F3' key to TcpClient using network stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, telnet, tcpclient, networkstream

i am making telnet session using c# and wanna to send 'F3' to the session

```
TcpClient oClient = new TcpClient();
oClient.Connect(IP, 23);  
NetworkStream ns = oClient.GetStream();
string msg=""// here to send 'F3' key
ns.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
```

i tried `"{F3}"` and `"\033[13~"` but didn't work

Comment: What do you mean by "F3"? The third function key on the keyboard with the label `F3`? If so, have you checked what you get if you read from standard input and press the key? Why not try sending that?

Comment: what do you mean by F3? Is this for VT100 or similar? you need to know what the byte sequence is; a bit of googling suggests "\033[13~" is the ASCII sequence that is used for F3, for example. It really depends what the server expects to hear. Another source suggests " ^[[13~"

Comment: yes the third function key

Comment: @MarcGravell i already tried this code , also didn't work

Comment: @CODER suggestion: connect a *working* client to a dummy endpoint, and see what that client sends you... duplicate that

Comment: So you want to just send F3, and not login or anything?  you dont seem to read any text have you read the output to see what happens?

Comment: @BugFinder i am already logged in but i didn't submit  all code lines

Comment: Yet another string to try (number 3): `"\x1bOR"`

Comment: @MarcGravell BTW when i send `Environment.NewLine` it's working , i will try number 3 and keep you update

Comment: @MarcGravell  "\x1bOR" its worked , Thanks a lot . you can post as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying data here is just a TCP stream that has no concept of a keyboard, so the real question is: what does the other end *expect* to that it is interpreting as `F3`? One way to do this would be to set up a dummy TCP dump console exe (server) and have a *working* client connect and press F3 - inspect what was sent. However, there are some likely candidates, including:

- `"^[[13~"`
- `"\033[13~"`
- `"\x1bOR"`

(for different client/server implementations)